# Javascript generating anchors quote issue

Tags: quote

I'm new to this site and new to Javascript, however I'm been coding in C for some years, and I ran into a problem that totally blows my mind.

I want to make a tool for myself (a very simple code generating tool). I want to generate html code and in a displayable manner, because the final product would be a static page (no javascript). So I tried to solve it with basic string manipulation.

The task and the code is so simple I'll just post it here.
Javascript with it's corresponding tags:

```js
<script>
function ConvertListToGallery()
{
    var cont = document.getElementById("gallery_generator_input");
    var eof_link;
    var eof_title;
    var eof_descr;
    var lines = [];
    var tokens = [];
    var i, k;
    var result = document.getElementById("gallery_generator_output");
    var link;
    var lofasz = [];

    if(cont)
    {
        lines = cont.value.split('\n');


        lofasz = cont.value.split('"');

        console.log(lofasz[0]);

        result.innerHTML = "";
   
        for( i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ )
        {
            tokens = lines[i].split(" + ");
            for( k = 0; k < tokens.length; k++ )
            {    console.log(tokens[k]);    }

            link = tokens[0];

            result.innerHTML += '<img src=' + link + '/>';
        }
        document.getElementById("gallery_generator_result").value=result.innerHTML;

        document.getElementById("gallery_convert").innerHTML = "Done!";
        document.getElementById("gallery_convert").onclick = "";
    }

}
</script>
```

The input:

> https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3ju3vX1o4OuY0RaaDJKWnlRN1U + title +
>   desc https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3ju3vX1o4OuSC1hNFQwUV9IWlE +
>   title2 + desc2

And the output after running the script:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3ju3vX1o4OuY0RaaDJKWnlRN1U/"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3ju3vX1o4OuSC1hNFQwUV9IWlE/">
```

It's like something automatically put quotes around the links. Sorry, I have tried so many things I can't remember now, but as I remember this "auto-quoting" thing only happens with links and it causes all sorts of problem in the resulting code (for example the '/' slips inside the quotes). And all other problems were caused by this behavior (I can't assign title and other attributes inside the img tag).

Additional html:

```
    <form>
    <textarea id="gallery_generator_input" style = "width:800px;"></textarea></form>

    <div id="gallery_generator_output" style="border:solid; max-height:500px; overflow:auto;">
    </div>

    <textarea id="gallery_generator_result" style = "width:800px;"></textarea>

<div onclick = "ConvertListToGallery();" id="gallery_convert">Convert!</div>
```

Thank you for any hints in advance!

EDIT: removed the misleading WOW thing.
The desired result is simply a valid html image code.

Comment: what is the desired result? is the desired result `<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3ju3vX1o4OuY0RaaDJKWnlRN1U" !!WOW>` ? try this `result.innerHTML += '<img src="' + link + '"!!WOW>';`

Comment: sorry, I don't know how the site works yet.
But your suggestion didn't work , only produced weird results.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
result.innerHTML += '<img src=' + link + '!!WOW>';
```

to this

```
result.innerHTML += '<img src="' + link + '!!WOW"/>';
```

also you can urlencode the exclamation marks if they are a problem:

```
result.innerHTML += '<img src="' + link + '%21%21WOW"/>';
```

Comment: I agree I think the op need to explicitly add the double quotes but am unsure this is the desired fix of having the `!!WOW` inside the quotes since he had this  in the  post `(for example the "!!WOW" slips inside the quotes).`

Comment: I know I have to add the double quotes but since the text gets the quotes from some totally obscure reason, that just causes other problems. for example "swallowing the" / from the end of the img tag and screwing any other attributes I would inside the img tag.

Comment: Actually, only the things between the link text and the closing > after it gets screwed. So if it's okay if there's no slash at the end of the img tag, then I'll live with it.

Comment: I added the proper close of the img tag using a `/>`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late follow-up, but it turned out that writing to the innerHMTL caused the issue (I'm still not sure if writing to innerHTML has some kind of obscure code fixing/completion feature). If I accumulate the HTML in a separate variable THEN assign it to the innerHTML has no issues.

I know that it's not the best practice to make dynamic code like that (the elements don't get added to the DOM tree), but for my use it's simpler to make the code this way, since it's only a tool for me to generate static pages.